# What is the Regression algo to Use for this case?

Tags: apache-spark, regression

Having this Data :

```
clientId zipCode codeHeatingType countingType consumptionProfile householdCount squareFootage 

01       75015  ELEC            P012            A400            6               25              

02       75002  GAZ             P011            A600            3               30
```

and the AvgConsumtion

```
clientId     AvgConsumption
  01           300.5      (KWH)
  02           400        (KWH)
```

What machine learning to use to estimate the Avgconsumption depending on the client characteristics ? LogisticRegression ?, multilabel classification ?...

is it possible to have an exemple with string colums ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a regression algorithm that predicts a continuous variable. You can find the list of regression algorithms implemented in `spark.ml` [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#regression) with exemples.

Categorical predictors can be transformed in various ways using non-parametric (non-optimized) `Transformer` (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html). For instance [OneHotEncoder](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder) will convert a categorical predictors in a set of binary predictors. Exemples are provided in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder).

Note: inform you on some basics in machine learning before trying too much. There is a series of pitfalls that are purely of statistical nature. For specific questions, ask [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: is the linear-regression or Generalized linear regression predict a continuous variable ? how to know if it does ?

Comment: all the methods in the section linked are regression methods (see table of content: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html). But not all models of regression will make sense in you context. This is not a syntax problem though, hence it is not in scope of StackOverflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i want to know wich are able to predict continuous variable? and wich are more adequate to my needs

Comment: cf. my answer for the first question. And for what concerns the adequacy to your needs, it is not relevant to StackOverflow, it is a machine learning problem, as I already said.